# Increased memory usage while zooming and dragging

Tags: arcgis-10.0

I have a problem that deals with memory. When I run my GIS program, it uses 495K from my memory after 1 minute. And it continues to work with same value.

[image]

But when I zoom in / zoom out / drag the map to other sides, the memory usage of my programme increases to 500-600K. and it does not decrease back to old value, it becomes constant value after the zooming and dragging stops.

[image]

I am clearing the unused memory all 1 second with:

```
GC.AddMemoryPressure(GC.GetTotalMemory(true));

GC.Collect(GC.MaxGeneration, GCCollectionMode.Forced);

GC.Collect();
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This may sound very counter intuitive, but turn off your memory collection.  I have had some massive issues with memory and the only way it ever improved, was by turning off the garbage collection....